# mount windows share read only

Tags: windows, cifs

I would like to mount a windows share which is read only for my backup user but I'm always getting the error message no permission.

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.0.10/office /mnt/shares/office -o ro,username=backup,password=mypassword,nodev,uid=backup,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

When I grant read / write permission on the folder mounting works and I can browse the folder, it just doesn't work when the folder is read only.

Comment: Are you setting the permissions on the Windows side or merely on the Linux side (in the mount command?)

Comment: I'm setting the permissions on the windows side, and I've also tried to set it in the mount command

Answer (score 6):

For anyone searching, this issue is due to not having cifs-utils. Install using:

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils
```